# Popup menu does not display the content, Empty menu

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

I'm coding on visual studio 2015 on windows 10. I created my popup menu and I filled it thanks to AppendMenu function. The menu has the right shape but the strings are not displayed. Does any one have a solution ?

Here is my code:

```
HMENU popMenu = CreatePopupMenu();
AppendMenu(popMenu, MF_STRING, ID_MENU_SHOW, "Show");
AppendMenu(popMenu, MF_STRING, ID_MENU_EXIT, "Exit");
POINT pCursor;
GetCursorPos(&pCursor);
SetForegroundWindow(msg->hwnd);
TrackPopupMenu(popMenu, TPM_BOTTOMALIGN | TPM_RIGHTALIGN | TPM_NONOTIFY |TPM_RETURNCMD | TPM_RIGHTBUTTON | TPM_VERNEGANIMATION, pCursor.x, pCursor.y, 0, msg->hwnd, NULL);
```

Comment: Try `AppendMenu(popMenu, MF_STRING, ID_MENU_SHOW, L"Show");` and `AppendMenu(popMenu, MF_STRING, ID_MENU_EXIT, L"Exit");`

Comment: Thank you but it still does not work.

Comment: Try this: `InsertMenu(popMenu, 0, MF_BYPOSITION | MF_STRING, ID_MENU_SHOW, L"Show");` etc

Comment: Thank you but it still does not work